# Prevent direct access to php file jquery load()

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to protect my PHP files from direct access, but my problem is that i do not include them in my index. I use jquery load() or iframe, so basicly the php files in include folder don't have access or code from index.php. So i tried with define CONST, but of course didn't work... So basicly i have URL site.com/file witch i load in my index with jquery load as a pop up, but i don\t want if someone try to access it directly from browser to have access... Any idea how should i protect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike's answer works for regular users, but if you need to be sure that the user first loads the index page, you could do something like:

1. generate a token when user loads index.php
2. add token to session data
3. add token to jquery load as a query parameter (e.g. `site.com/file?token=xxxx`)
4. on `file` load, compare token passed as parameter to the one stored in session and clear the session, so it cannot reuse the token

This way, the user is required to load `index.php` before loading `file`.

It wouldn't prevent an advanced user from acessing the `file` page directly after having the token.

Answer (score 0):

try this, first block limits access to ajax requests, second one checks referring url is mywebsite

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){  
    echo "<span class='error_msgh'>Error 1. Process Aborted.</span>";
    die();
}elseif(!preg_match('/(www.mywebsite.com)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    echo "<span class='error_msgh'>Error 2. Process Aborted.</span>";
    die(); 
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, an user could spoof these headers anyway and still view the page. But would prevent the regular user from doing that.